# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support all major browsers or just chrome?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have looked into the documentation of FCM and it mentions that it cross platform. Anyhow [FCM for Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) documentation talks about Chrome. I want to check whether FCM supports messaging to all major web browsers including IE, Safari and Firefox?

Comment: It seems like it is only chrome

Answer (score 8):

The link you mentioned is talking about FCM support for Chrome apps and extensions only, it's a different story for the web.

FCM supports Web Push Protocol, according to this article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/web-push-interop-wins

> Now that FCM supports Web Push Protocol you can leave the endpoint intact and use the URL as a Web Push Protocol endpoint. (This brings it in line with Firefox and hopefully every other future browser.)
>
> You no longer need a Firebase project, a gcm_sender_id, or an Authorization header.

Both Chrome and Firefox use the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) for push notifications and Firefox already supports Web Push Protocol, which means by updating FCM server-side code, it will work for both Chrome and Firefox.

Google really needs to update their docs as [Enable Push Notifications for your Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en) is out of date.

It won't work with IE and Safari as they don't support the Push API at all.

Comment: Push should also work in Opera and Edge has it in development. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/pushapi/?q=push

Comment: Safari supports push notifications through APNS (same service used to send push notifications to iphone apps).